# Mono - ASP.NET Application in domain Subfolder

Tags: asp.net, mono, apache2, mod-mono

I have an Apache server with mod_mono hooked up to a legacy ASP.NET application. I can't seem to get this application to work if I move it from a top level folder.

For example, the following mono `.webapp` successfully works at `http://localhost/Service.asmx` (as my web app is in `folder2`):

```
<apps>
<web-application>
                <name>Test</name>
                <vpath>/</vpath>
                <path>/srv/aspnettest/folder1/folder2</path>
                <vhost>localhost</vhost>
        </web-application>
</apps>
```

However, due to a legacy URL, I need my web application to exist two subfolders deeper like so:

```
<apps>
<web-application>
                <name>Test</name>
                <vpath>/</vpath>
                <path>/srv/aspnettest/</path>
                <vhost>localhost</vhost>
        </web-application>
</apps>
```

If I try to go to `http://localhost/folder1/folder2/Service.asmx` it fails with

```
HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.Web.HttpException: Type MyType.Service not found.
  at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetTypeFromBin (System.String tname) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.SimpleBuildProvider.LoadTypeFromBin (System.Web.Compilation.BaseCompiler compiler, System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser parser) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.GenericBuildProvider`1[TParser].GetGeneratedType (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerCacheItem..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider bp, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.StoreInCache (System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider bp, System.Reflection.Assembly compiledAssembly, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String verb, System.String url, System.String filePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url, Boolean ignoreContextHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How can I successfully get a web app in subfolders? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an Apache configuration issue that was unrelated but caused this as a side effect. I had my VirtualHost setup incorrectly.